# Location of the point P

Tags: geometric-construction

A portion of a sketch drawn by a student to obtain the
location of a point P which lies at a distance of 3cm from
the given straight line AB and 5cm from the point A, is
shown in the figure. Complete the sketch and mark the
location of the point P.

[image]

Any ideas on how to begin?

Comment: Put point $P'$ with a distance 4cm from $A$, then draw a perpendicular line to $AB$ at $P'$ then the intersection of the perpendicular line and $CD$ is your point $P$

Comment: It's the same point where AB is 4 cm the line CD is 4cm .Is that point P? and why chose 4cm away from AB instead of 5 which the question mentions

Comment: $|AP'|=4$ implies $|AP|=5$

Comment: using set notation i guess? and why use "  '  " the dash of the lines

Comment: By Pythagoras Theorem $|AP'|^2+|PP'|^2 = |PP'|^2$ since $|AP'|=4$ and $|PP'|=3$ we have $|AP|=5$

Comment: If a compass is allowed then draw circle centered at A with radius 5 cm. Intersection of this circle and your line CD is point P.